# git branch contents different from remote

Tags: git

Hi I wanted to switch to a specific branch, `part1-es6`

[image]

but, when I clone this repo and checkout this branch, the files list differently, what am I doing wrong. Also, `git branch` doesn't list any!! other than master.

```
bsr[~/tmp] $ git clone https://github.com/jlongster/backend-with-webpack.git
Cloning into 'backend-with-webpack'...
remote: Counting objects: 106, done.
remote: Total 106 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 106
Receiving objects: 100% (106/106), 88.28 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (41/41), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
bsr[~/tmp] $ git branch
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
bsr[~/tmp] $ cd backend-with-webpack/
bsr[~/tmp/backend-with-webpack] [master] $ git branch
* master
bsr[~/tmp/backend-with-webpack] [master] $ git checkout -b part1-es6
Switched to a new branch 'part1-es6'
bsr[~/tmp/backend-with-webpack] [part1-es6] $ ls
README.md    build        gulpfile.js  package.json src          static
bsr[~/tmp/backend-with-webpack] [part1-es6] $
```

Comment: I think you are creating a new brach rather than fetching part-es6 from remote repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `git checkout -t origin/part1-es6` after you clone the repository.

Comment: thanks. it works !!  do you know why it doesn't list all the branches with `git branch` ?

Comment: you can  use `git branch -r` to list the remote-tracking branches. @bsr